# passing option to ant in cruisecontrol

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

I have following code in  `config.xml` file:

```
<schedule interval = "300">
    <ant     anthome="/usr/share/ant"
         antworkingdir="${GitDir}"
         uselogger="true"
         usedebug="true"/>
</schedule>
```

And when I execute build through it, I am just getting output, like I've been typing just `ant` in command line.
I need to be able to execute following command from Cruisecontrol:

```
ant debug
```

If this is making any difference, I need to be able to build android application.
How this can be done?
Thank you on advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using the right attributes in your config.xml to start your ant scripts with loglevel debug

```
...
usedebug="true"
...
```

is equivalent to `ant -debug ...`
see http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#ant for details.

Comment: I thought so too, but according to output which I am getting, it is not so, I'm getting the same output like when I type just ant in command line.

Comment: I am trying to build android application is this making anny difference?

Comment: sorry for late response; the android app shouldn't a problem; used cruisecontrol several years ago, don't remember any bugs in the logger area, do you use any special loggger, i.e. log4j ?

Comment: Which "output" are you referring to? The email content or the build log? The build log will have everything in it. The emails may have less than you expect because of how the xml is setup in the build log. I think only xml messages coded as warnings or errors make it into the emails.